# Cognos SQL multiple rows to one row

Tags: cognos-10

The issue I'm having is that the note table allows for multiple entries and I would like it to be in one row for each stock code. I would like this done on the query side.   I have tired to several different ways that I know in sql to do it but I keep getting unrecognizable query framework response(example shown blow

stock_code      note_sequence             stock_note 
++++++++++  +++++++++++++   ++++++++++ 
3051715                1                     Sold in sets
3051715                2                    
From vendor 9999 15; but 
3051715                3                     will be sold separately 
   
stock_code             stock_note 
++++++++++  +++++++++++++
 
3051715    Sold in sets,From vendor 999 15; but will be sold separately

Answer (score 0):

Add three new data items, we'll call them *NS 1*, *NS 2*, and *NS 3*.

**NS 1**

```
CASE [note_sequence] 
WHEN 1 THEN [stock_note] 
ELSE null 
END
```

**NS 2**

```
CASE [note_sequence] 
WHEN 2 THEN [stock_note] 
ELSE null 
END
```

**NS 3**

```
CASE [note_sequence] 
WHEN 3 THEN [stock_note] 
ELSE null 
END
```

Set the Aggregate Function of each new data item to 'Maximum'.

In order to concatenate the results you will have to create a new query and make the existing query the source for the new query. Pull in all of the data items from the original query.

In the new query create a new data item called *stock_notes* with the following expression:

```
[NS 1] || ',' || [NS 2] || ',' || [NS 3]
```

The result should be one row per *stock_code* and the new data item *stock_notes* will have all of the appropriate notes for each stock code in a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0):

There is an object in Report Studio called *Repeater*. A *Repeater* is a data container that has to be linked to a *query*. Inside a *Repeater* you can place a *TextItem* linked to the data item `stock_note`, and another *TextItem* with the comma.

You can place the *Repeater* in a column of the *List* (created for example adding to the edge of the list a *TextItem* or a *Query Calculation*). Once you have added this column to the *List*, click in the padlock icon and place the *Repeater* **inside** the column.

The query of the repeater has to be linked to the query of the list through a **master-detail relationship** (look in the properties of the Repeater query)

(The drawback of master-detail relationships is a loss of performance)